# Can the Sieve of Eratosthenes be adapted to find twin primes

Tags: algorithms, recursion, primes

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is an algorithm generate the prime numbers, $2,3,5,7,11,13,...$ by drawing a list of numbers crossing out multiples of the smallest number in the list.

Is there anyway to modify this algorithm to search for *[twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime)* up to $N$?

One way would be to, generate the list of primes $p < \sqrt{N}$ and crossing out multiples of those primes should give prime numbers up to $N$.  Then we can check $p \pm 2$ and see if they also appear in the list.

<sub>I posted [a related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25527/sieve-methods-for-twin-primes-how-to-extract-algorithm-from-formula) about whether we actually have to generate all primes for this task on cstheory.SE.</sub>

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your own question: the answer is yes, you can, by finding all prime numbers up to $N$, then for each prime $p$, checking $p+2$ to see if it also is in the list.  So what's left to answer?  What is the question?